# My Click events aren't working I'm not getting any errors they just won't work

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a project for the university where we must make a website for a company called quick breaks. It must let the user buy items that add to or less than $15. The problem I am having is that when I click my labels, nothing happens. It should add to the cost which is the paragraph called `c`.

JavaScript:

```
var FirstName;
var LastName;
var cost = 0.0;

function Coke() {
  if (cost + 2.99 >= 15) {
    Cost += 2.99;
    document.getElementById("c").value = cost;
  }
}

function Sundae() {
  if (cost + 4.40 >= 15) {
    Cost += 4.40;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Pizza() {
  if (cost + 7.53 >= 15) {
    cost += 7.53;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function CheeseBurger() {
  if (cost + 6.52 >= 15) {
    cost += 6.52;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Salad() {
  if (cost + 7.47 >= 15) {
    cost += 7.47;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Coffee() {
  if (cost + 3.89 >= 15) {
    cost += 3.89;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Clear() {
  Cost = 0;
  FirstName = "";
  LastName = "";
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html!>
<html>

</html>

<head>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="JavaScript.js" rel="script"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assesmentcss.css">

<header>
  <h1 id="title"> Quick Breaks Lunches </h1>
  <br>
  <div id="Details" class="Details">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"> Mobile: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
</header>

<body>
  <div id="images">
    <img src="Coke.png" alt="Coke Can" onclick="Coke();">
    <img src="Sundae.png" alt="Sundae" onclick="Sundae();">
    <img src="Pizza.png" alt="Pizza" onclick="Pizza();">
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="images">
    <img src="CheeseBurger.png" alt="CheeseBurger" onclick="CheeseBurger();">
    <img src="Salad.png" alt="Salad" onclick="Salad();">
    <img src="Coffee.png" alt="Coffee" onclick="Coffee();">
  </div>
  <div Class="Price">
    Coke:$2.99 Sundae:$4.40 Pizza: $7.53 <br> CheeseBurger: $6.52 Salad: $7.47 Coffee: $3.89 <br> You can spend $15
  </div>
  <div Class="amountSpent">
    You Have Spent
    <p id="c"></p>
  </div>

  <div Class="OrderAndClear">
    <br>
    <button type="button">Order </button> <button type="button" onclick="Clear">Clear </button>
  </div>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: any error you get in the console ?

Comment: The `if()` conditions will never be true. Also, `Cost` should be `cost`, since Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: I think `>= 15` is supposed to be `<= 15`, since `$15` is your spending limit.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code:

- You set the `cost` variable to zero, so none of the conditions in your functions will evaluate to true. So the functions may work but you'll see no results. Fix the conditions (change `>=` to `<=`.
- In the `Coke()`, `Sundae()`, and `Clear()` functions, you capitalized the first letter of the `cost` variable.
- In the `Coke()` function, you used the `value` property. It should be `innerHTML` like the other functions, so I think this was a typo.
- Your `Clear()` function is clearing the variables, but maybe you want to reset the form too?

```js
var FirstName;
var LastName;
var cost = 0.0;


function Coke() {
  if (cost + 2.99 <= 15) {
    cost += 2.99;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Sundae() {
  if (cost + 4.40 <= 15) {
    cost += 4.40;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Pizza() {
  if (cost + 7.53 <= 15) {
    cost += 7.53;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function CheeseBurger() {
  if (cost + 6.52 <= 15) {
    cost += 6.52;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Salad() {
  if (cost + 7.47 <= 15) {
    cost += 7.47;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Coffee() {
  if (cost + 3.89 <= 15) {
    cost += 3.89;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Clear() {
  cost = 0;
  FirstName = "";
  LastName = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html!>
<html>

</html>

<head>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="JavaScript.js" rel="script"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assesmentcss.css">

<header>
  <h1 id="title"> Quick Breaks Lunches </h1>
  <br>
  <div id="Details" class="Details">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"> Mobile: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  </div>
</header>

<body>
  <div id="images">
    <img src="Coke.png" alt="Coke Can" onclick="Coke();">
    <img src="Sundae.png" alt="Sundae" onclick="Sundae();">
    <img src="Pizza.png" alt="Pizza" onclick="Pizza();">
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="images">
    <img src="CheeseBurger.png" alt="CheeseBurger" onclick="CheeseBurger();">
    <img src="Salad.png" alt="Salad" onclick="Salad();">
    <img src="Coffee.png" alt="Coffee" onclick="Coffee();">
  </div>
  <div Class="Price">
    Coke:$2.99 Sundae:$4.40 Pizza: $7.53 <br> CheeseBurger: $6.52 Salad: $7.47 Coffee: $3.89 <br> You can spend $15
  </div>
  <div Class="amountSpent">
    You Have Spent
    <p id="c"></p>
  </div>

  <div Class="OrderAndClear">
    <br>
    <button type="button">Order </button> <button type="button" onclick="Clear">Clear </button>
  </div>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Note: Since all those function are identical, it is recommended to follow the DRY principle and extract the code to one function and call it from all these functions:

```
var FirstName;
var LastName;
var cost = 0.0;

function Coke() {
  CalculateTotal(2.99);
}

function Sundae() {
  CalculateTotal(4.40);
}

function Pizza() {
  CalculateTotal(7.53);
}

function CheeseBurger() {
  CalculateTotal(6.52);
}

function Salad() {
  CalculateTotal(7.47);
}

function Coffee() {
  CalculateTotal(3.89);
}

function CalculateTotal(itemCost) {
  if (cost + itemCost <= 15) {
    cost += itemCost;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}
```

You can even pass the cost of each item directly from the items themselves and then you only need the `CalculateTotal()` function:

```
<div id="images">
  <img src="Coke.png" alt="Coke Can" onclick="CalculateTotal(2.99);">
  <img src="Sundae.png" alt="Sundae" onclick="CalculateTotal(4.40);">
  <img src="Pizza.png" alt="Pizza" onclick="CalculateTotal(7.53);">
  <br>
</div>

<div id="images">
  <img src="CheeseBurger.png" alt="CheeseBurger" onclick="CalculateTotal(6.52);">
  <img src="Salad.png" alt="Salad" onclick="CalculateTotal(7.47);">
  <img src="Coffee.png" alt="Coffee" onclick="CalculateTotal(3.89);">
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of setting cost to 100, I think you should change `>=` to `<=`. It says that you can spend up to $15, so that's a maximum of the cost, not a minimum.

Comment: @Barmar Hmmm... Good point... I was focused on the condition being false and didn't try to interpret it. I will update.

Comment: There are various errors in the HTML as well, that you didn't correct. `!` in the doctype, `</html>` at the top, `<header>`  in between the `</head>` and the `<body>`, duplicate ids, etc.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, there are even more errors than what you mentioned, but I only focused on JavaScript to answer the question and because those HTML errors don't prevent the demo from working. But your note is useful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There are variable mistake `cost` and `Cost` and there is also mistake in logic, please check and compare with below:-

```js
var FirstName;
var LastName;
var cost = 0.0;


function Coke() {

  if (cost + 2.99 < 15) {
    cost += 2.99;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Sundae() {
  if (cost + 4.40 < 15) {
    cost += 4.40;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Pizza() {
  if (cost + 7.53 < 15) {
    cost += 7.53;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function CheeseBurger() {
  if (cost + 6.52 < 15) {
    cost += 6.52;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Salad() {
  if (cost + 7.47 < 15) {
    cost += 7.47;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Coffee() {
  if (cost + 3.89 < 15) {
    cost += 3.89;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = cost;
  }
}

function Clear() {
  cost = 0;
  FirstName = "";
  LastName = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html!>
<html>

</html>

<head>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="JavaScript.js" rel="script"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assesmentcss.css">

<header>
  <h1 id="title"> Quick Breaks Lunches </h1>
  <br>
  <div id="Details" class="Details">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"> Mobile: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
</header>

<body>
  <div id="images">
    <img src="Coke.png" alt="Coke Can" onclick="Coke();">
    <img src="Sundae.png" alt="Sundae" onclick="Sundae();">
    <img src="Pizza.png" alt="Pizza" onclick="Pizza();">
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="images">
    <img src="CheeseBurger.png" alt="CheeseBurger" onclick="CheeseBurger();">
    <img src="Salad.png" alt="Salad" onclick="Salad();">
    <img src="Coffee.png" alt="Coffee" onclick="Coffee();">
  </div>
  <div Class="Price">
    Coke:$2.99 Sundae:$4.40 Pizza: $7.53 <br> CheeseBurger: $6.52 Salad: $7.47 Coffee: $3.89 <br> You can spend $15
  </div>
  <div Class="amountSpent">
    You Have Spent
    <p id="c"></p>
  </div>

  <div Class="OrderAndClear">
    <br>
    <button type="button">Order </button> <button type="button" onclick="Clear">Clear </button>
  </div>
</body>


<footer>
</footer>
```